# Android Bluetooth / Asynchronous AIDL / Callbacks

Tags: java, android, ipc, aidl

Let us say we have a device emitting Bluetooth data, in which a producer app has bonded with, in order to project an average interval of data items to a consumer app on the same system image as the producer. For the producer and consumer relationship, I have chosen to use one asynchronous aidl to consume the Bluetooth data and a callback aidl to return the payload to the consumer. (AIDL UNDERSTANDING) For clarity, the consumer has declared BOTH of the aidl interfaces in the same packages as the producer has done to follow the rules of aidl communication.The consumer app will declare a callback stub and pass it to the bound service it created by calling bindService(..) in order to be notified when the producer's remote service has finished its data processing. After the client gets the first payload I want to unbind from the service to build a real time chart; the problem is that the consumer app continues to receive data items emitted from the producer's remote service for a few seconds after the consumer has unbound from the service. This causes my app to construct and destruct computational graphs and then return one final graph

```
          final IUsageServiceCallBack.Stub callback = new 
        IUsageServiceCallBack.Stub() {
                         @Override
                         public void onResult(Bundle usageBundle) 
              throws RemoteException {
                             Log.i(TAG , "BLUETOOTH DATA" );
                             // Perform Logic 
                             // Unbind but onResult still called
                         }
                     };
```

Is there a good solution to handle this scenario. I have thought of adding flags but that is not good

Comment: where are you using `IUsageServiceCallBack.Stub callback` ? where do you pass it?

Comment: The consumer app will pass a final reference of the callback to the bound service it has established a connection with in the producer app

Comment: This is explained in the question btw

Comment: take a look into [that](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.java) service, here is [AIDL](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/IRemoteService.aidl)

Comment: hi can you give some description about handle messages() .

Comment: this is not important, important part is AIDL, it should have those `register` / `unregister` methods, so after you call `unregister` you will receive no further data

Comment: the reason i asked is that the mhandler code is used in the callbacks.

Comment: i will test the service when i get home to my computer but just if you can let me know why we would run it on the main thread it says like  /**
     * Our Handler used to execute operations on the main thread.  This is used
     * to schedule increments of our value.
     */

Comment: Sir @pskink waiting for you Knowledge Transfer. ask yourself do you share the knowledge or do you hide it.

Comment: what problems do you have with register / unregister methods?

Comment: why we would run it on the main thread it says like /** * Our Handler used to execute operations on the main thread. This is used * to schedule increments of our value. */